# Remove duplicates from ArrayLists

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of custom objects. I want to remove duplicate entries.

The objects have three fields: `title, subtitle`, and `id`. If a subtitle occurs multiple times, I only need the first item with thats subtitle (ignore the remaining object with that subtitle).

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, using a Set in the first place would be simpler.

Comment: i have use tree set and add the subtitle in tree if the add method return true i add the object in another arraylist

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can put the content of the ArrayList in a TreeSet using a custom Comparator which should return 0 if the two subtitles are the same.
After that you can convert the Set in a List and have the List without "duplicates".
Here is an example for Object, of course you should use the correct class and logic.

```
public void removeDuplicates(List<Object> l) {
    // ... the list is already populated
    Set<Object> s = new TreeSet<Object>(new Comparator<Object>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            // ... compare the two object according to your requirements
            return 0;
        }
    });
            s.addAll(l);
    List<Object> res = Arrays.asList(s.toArray());
}
```

Comment: I think overriding equals() (and hashCode()) as suggested on several answers below is a better solution, and moreover, your "removeDuplicates(...)" method doesn't remove duplicates from the "l" list : it doesn't even use "l".

Comment: you're right, I forgot a line, the code is correct now.
As for overriding equals and hashset I disagree as a general solution; overriding them is much more invasive than my solution, which would work even if you can't modify the original class.
My 2c anyway, I accept the -1 for posting wrong code; I'm always open for critics

Comment: But it's a good practice to override equals and hashcode to make business unicity more explicit : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode

Comment: of course, if the order I want si ok as a natural (universal) order and I can modify the original classes I would definitely go for equals, hasCode or better even implement Comparable.
But I have seen business requirements where I had to order objects in a different order than the natual one, and using a Comparator always works even if the previous conditions are not met.
In general there is no best approach here, it depends on the scenario.

Comment: i have use tree set and add the subtiles if the tree set add return true i add my object in another arraylist :

Comment: This approach doesn't preserve the original ordering of the arraylist, right?

Comment: It's not guaranteed; I just used a treeset because it is simpler (IMHO) to implement custom compare logic. Of course I could have used a HashSet, but that would have required to define hashCode putting there comparation logic, which seems foreign to me

Comment: It's not guaranteed; I get duplicates from 400 custom objects

Comment: This works, but is really inefficient for both CPU and memory, as it allocates giant amount of memory, and since it's a TreeSet, it's not localized (= high CPU cache miss rate). See below for my solution that arranges this in-place.

Comment: ok, fair point if your input set is very large; as already stated, mine works even in the case the object doesn't implement Comparator or the unicity is calculated in a different way than the sorting (some part of the string may be relevant to sorting but not for unicity)

Answer (score 46):

```
List list = (...);

//list may contain duplicates.

//remove duplicates if any
Set setItems = new LinkedHashSet(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(setItems);
```

You may need to override "equals()" so that 2 elements are considered equals if they have the same subtitle (or tite and subtitle maybe ?)

Comment: ... but does not work if the object has a member which is used for sorting, as the hash is different even if the key is the same (if other fields differ).

Answer (score 12):

```
List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
Set<String> titles = new HashSet<String>();

for(Item item : originalList) {
    if(titles.add(item.getTitle()) {
        result.add(item);
    }
}
```

`add()` of the `Set` returns `false` if the element already exists.

Comment: You are best :) It is better than Riccardo Cossu

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using a Set

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Which by its nature cannot contain duplicate items. You can create a new set from your original ArrayList using

```
Set myset = new HashSet(myArrayList);
```

Alternatively, just use a Set from the start, and don't use an ArrayList as it is not performing the function that you require.

Comment: One should NOT rely on equals and hashcode in this case, since the example is only looking for equality on one property. Instead create a new list with the wanted result.

Comment: If that one property is what marks the object as unique, why should he not override equals so that it only checks that one property?

Comment: Yes, if using equals is great (f.e. in some Frameworks datasets) and you want to unify your ArrayList you can do it with: `myArrayList = new ArrayList(new HashSet(myArrayList));` But this is heavy work and you should do it just if you have to rely on lists in future Code (like `Collections.shuffle()`)

Answer (score 7):

You can use an O(n^2) solution: Use `list.iterator()` to iterate the list once, and on each iteration, iterate it again to check if there are duplicates. If there are - call `iterator.remove()`. A variation of this is to use guava's `Iterables.filter(list, predicate)` where your filtering logic is in the predicate.

Another way (perhaps better) would be to define the `equals(..)` and `hashCode(..)` methods to handle your custom equality logic, and then simply construct a `new HashSet(list)`. This will clear duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly you have an `ArrayList<Custom>`, let's call it `list`. Your `Custom` class has a subtitle field, let's say with a `getSubtitle()` method that returns `String`. You want to keep only the first unique subtitle and remove any remaining duplicates. Here's how you can do that:

```
Set<String> subtitles = new HashSet<String>();
for (Iterator<Custom> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    if (!subtitles.add(it.next().getSubtitle())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Removes any duplicates in a collection, while preserving the order if it is an ordered collection. Efficient enough for most cases.

```
public static <I, T extends Collection<I>> T removeDuplicates(T collection)
{
    Set<I> setItems = new LinkedHashSet<I>(collection);
    collection.clear();
    collection.addAll(setItems);

    return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Java8:**

Using Java8 streams you can also do pretty trivally.

```
ArrayList<String> deduped;
deduped = yourArrayList.stream()
             .distinct()
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This also has the advantage over going *ArrayList*  → *Set*   → *ArrayList*     of maintaining ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Use Collections.sort() to sort and use a simple for cycle to catch doubles, e.g.:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
A previous = null;
for (A elem: myList) {
    if (elem.compareTo(previous) == 0) continue;
    previous = elem;

    [... process unique element ...]
}
```

This presumes that you'll implement Comparable in your type A.

Comment: more efficient but less flexible; it's probably better for large input sets

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<Integer> removeDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {
    ArrayList<Integer> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
        if (!inArray(i, uniqueList)) {
            uniqueList.add(i);
        }
    }

    return uniqueList;
}

private static boolean inArray(Integer i, List<Integer> list) {
    for (Integer integer : list) {
        if (integer == i) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works only with a list of `Integer`s. The OP specifically said the list contains custom objects.

Comment: well .. substitute integer for those objects and change the condition in ´inArray´ ...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<YourObject> all = ******** // this is the object that you have already  and filled it.
List<YourObject> noRepeat= new ArrayList<YourObject>();

for (YourObject al: all) {
    boolean isPresent = false;
    // check if the current objects subtitle already exists in noRepeat
    for (YourObject nr : noRepeat) {
        if (nr.getName().equals(al.getName()) {
            isFound = true;//yes we have already
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isPresent)
        noRepeat.add(al); // we are adding if we don't have already
}
```

> take one new  ArrayList Object of same type
>   one by one add all the old arraylists elements into this new arraylist object 
>   but before adding every object check in the new arraylist that if there is any object with the same subtitle.if new arraylist contains such subtitle don't add it. otherwise add it

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on circumstances.

If you don't have much data then go with a Set `Set<T> unique = new HashSet<>(yourList);` (use LinkedHashSet if you care about the order. It creates a new collection, but usually it's not a problem.

When you want to modify existing list and don't want to/can't create a new collection, you can remove duplicates like here:

```
List<Integer> numbers =
    new ArrayList<>(asList(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5));

System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers);
ListIterator<Integer> it = numbers.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    int i = it.nextIndex();
    Integer current = it.next();
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        if (current.equals(numbers.get(j))) {
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Unique: " + numbers);
```

It works in O(n^2), but it works. Similar implementation, but simpler, is when the list is sorted - works in O(n) time. Both implementations are explained at Farenda: [remove duplicates from list - various implementations](http://farenda.com/java/java-remove-duplicates-from-list/).

Answer (score 0):

Another method using Java 8 streams you can also do pretty cool:

```
List<Customer> CustomerLists;
List<Customer> unique = CustomerLists.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(
        toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingLong(Customer::getId))),
        ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can also do something like this:

```
yourList.stream().collect(
     Collectors.toMap(
         obj -> obj.getSubtitle(),
         Function.identity(), 
         (o1,o2) -> o1))
    .values();
```

The trick is to collect stream to map and provide key collision resolver lambda (`(o1,o2) -> o1`) which always returns its first parameter.
The result is a Collection, not a List but you can easily convert it to a List:

```
new ArrayList(resultCollection);
```