# Filter non duplicate from ArrayList

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java ArrayList remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741038/java-arraylist-remove-duplicates)

From follwing class and list ,I need a list  where name and date same and other should get remove .

from below list I need only first two records , because name and date are same third one should be delete.Could some one help me out.

```
public class TestBean {

    public String name;
    public Date birthDate;
    public String city;
}


List<TestBean> list = new ArrayList<TestBean>();

TestBean testBean=new TestBean();
testBean.setName("test");
testBean.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse("01/01/1981"));
testBean.setCity("chicago");

TestBean testBean1=new TestBean();
testBean.setName("test");
testBean.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse("01/01/1981"));
testBean.setCity("newyork");

TestBean testBean2=new TestBean();

testBean.setName("test");
testBean.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse("01/01/1982"));
testBean.setCity("chicago");
list.add(testBean);
list.add(testBean1);
list.add(testBean2);
```

Comment: Anything tried??, just add to what you tried, if landed with error post the error

Comment: use a `Set` data structure.

Comment: Try to move your wanted data to another list by  using comparator.In comparator implemented class write your custom compare method

Answer (score 2):

Override equals() (based on name and birth date) and hashCode() for TestBean class and then add all the objects to [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) data structure. Set filters duplicate objects provided you have equals() overridden correctly.