# Merging Arraylist of Objects and removing duplicates based on a field value

Tags: java

I am looking for the best solution to my below requirements.

I have a class similar to `ClassA` below

```
public class ClassA {
    protected List<ClassA.PlanA> planA;

    public List<ClassA.PlanA> getPricePlan() {
        if (planA == null)
            planA = new ArrayList<ClassA.PlanA>();
        return this.planA;
    }

    public static class PlanA {
        protected String code;
        protected XMLGregorianCalendar startDate;
        protected XMLGregorianCalendar endDate;

        // Getters and setters for the above fields
    }   
}
```

And I have two objects `(obj1, ojb2)` of `ClassA`. The requirement is to merge the two objects and remove the duplicates.

Example:

```
ClassA obj1=[PlanA =[code=AAA, startDate=2010/12/10, endDate=2011/12/10], PlanA =[code=BBB, startDate=2010/12/10 endDate=<null>]] 

ClassA obj2=[PlanA=[code=AAA, startDate=2011/12/10], PlanA= [code=CC, startDate=2011/12/10 endDate=<null>], PlanA= [code=BBB, startDate=2010/12/10 endDate=2011/12/10]]
```

After merging the result should look like:

```
ClassA obj3=[PlanA[code=AAA, startDate=2011/12/10], PlanA= [code=CC, startDate=2011/12/10 endDate=<null>],PlanA= [code=BBB, startDate=2010/12/10 endDate=<null>]}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from ArrayLists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741038/remove-duplicates-from-arraylists)

Comment: I would Override the 'equals(Object obj)' method in planA and use a Set instead of an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `equals` and `hashcode` for `PlanA`:

```java
public static class PlanA {

    protected String code;
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar startDate;
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar endDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof PlanA && obj.hashCode() == hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { code, startDate, endDate });
    }

}
```

Then use a `Set`:

```java
Set<ClassA.PlanA> merged = new HashSet<ClassA.PlanA>();
merged.addAll(obj1.getPricePlan());
merged.addAll(obj2.getPricePlan());
```

A `Set` automatically removes duplicates.

Comment: One of the requirements that I want to highlight is, when removing the duplicates it should also check if the endDate is present. If the endDate is present then remove that object from the list.
In my above example I have like this,
Obj1 PlanA=[code=AAA, startDate=2010/12/10, endDate=2011/12/10]
Obj2 PlanA=[code=AAA, startDate=2011/12/10]
Now the result after merging should have code=AAA, startDate=2011/12/10