# remove duplicated elements from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

In my program I have an array list containing product objects in it. I want to remove duplicated product objects from it. Is there any efficient way other than looping over each element and compare them.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741038/remove-duplicates-from-arraylists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Set` but you will loose the original order of your list.

What you can do to keep the order is:

```
Set<E> copied = new HashSet<>();
List<E> res = new ArrayList<>();
for(E e : originalList) {
    if(!copied.contains(e)) {
        res.add(e);
    }
    copied.add(e);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

just add all element into `set`. it wont allow duplicate values

```
   List<Product> list=new ArrayList<>();
   Set<Product> set=new HashSet<>();
   set.addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just put element into `Set`. Set keep unique values only.

```
   List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
   Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
   set.addAll(list); // now you have unique value set
```

If you want to final result as unique value `List` just you need to get this `Set` as `List`

```
   List<String> uniqueValList=new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just pass your list Collection to `Hashset` constructor and Get it back.

Then that one liner will be,

```
list = new ArrayList<E>(new HashSet<E>(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of list it will remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of List. Set wont allow duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

The advice above to use Set is good - but if you need to keep the order just use a LinkedHashSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

```
List<String> list = ...
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

That will preserve order and remove all duplicates.

The result will be case sensitive though in the case of strings.