# Amending duplicate items inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called `Feeds` which contains many member variables. Among them is the variable `date` of type `String`. I implement an `ArrayList` of Feeds and add objects sequentially.

What i want to do is to search for objects that have the same date `String` and if the occurrence is more than 1 the repeated date `String` is made to be `""` (empty) BUT you will still have one object that has that date String intact.

Something like this:

```
Object1 (date : "01-01-2015");
Object2 (date : "01-01-2015");
Object3 (date : "04-01-2015");

//after the required code

Object1 (date : "01-01-2015");
Object2 (date : "");
Object3 (date : "04-01-2015");

List<Feeds> mFeeds = new ArrayList<Feeds>();
//add objects to list
mFeeds.add(...);

for(Feeds f : mFeeds){
   //search for objects that have the same date
   //skip the first repeatable and make the rest empty ""
}
```

Comment: You probably should use a `Set` and a suitable `equals()` not the algorithm you describe

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741038/remove-duplicates-from-arraylists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet<String>` to find out whether you already encountered the date :

```
Set<String> dups = new HashSet<> ();
for(Feeds f : mFeeds) {
    if (dups.contains(f.getDate())
        f.setDate(null); // this date already appeared in the list, so set it to null
    else
        dups.add(f.getDate()); // this is the first occurrence of this date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java8 it's a one-liner:

```
Set<String> dups = mFeeds.stream().map(f -> f.getDate()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```