# How to sort and eliminate the duplicates from ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList` of `String` type which contains values as `range = {300-400, 100-200, 500-600, 300-400, 500-600}`

I need to sort it out and remove the duplicates present in it.

The final output should be `range = {100-200,300-400,500-600}`.

I have tried using HashSet its removing the duplicates but sorting order is not maintained.

`Set<String> ol = new HashSet<String>(mylist);`

Comment: `Collections.sort(yourList)` should be enough, as the natural order of numbers fits your requirements. So much for the sorting part. For the duplicates, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741038/remove-duplicates-from-arraylists

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 14):

```
list
    .stream()
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: nice. simple and elegant.

Comment: It would be much faster for large lists to use `sorted()` before `distinct()`: `list.stream().sorted().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 11):

Use a `TreeSet`:

```
Set<String> sortedAndDistinct = new TreeSet<>(list);
```

A `Set` allows by definition only distinct values. And a `TreeSet` sorts the values according to their natural ordering (if no `Comparator` is provided at creation).

For `String`s the natural ordering is lexicographically, in other words, `a` is smaller than `z` or in your case `100-200` is smaller than `500-600`

Comment: Assuming the asker doesn't care that they aren't getting a List back, I'd prefer this solution to my own. Nice.